# Processing of batch updates in UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, io, uicollectionview

I'm building a data source, that should update a `UICollectionView` when it's content changes (a bit like `NSFetchedResultsController`). For this I have to derive the *change actions* based on the correct indexes.

The documentation contains only paragraph [paragraph](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/performBatchUpdates:completion:) regarding the processing of the batch operation, and this is also a bit confusing.

> Deletes are processed before inserts in batch operations. This means the indexes for the insertions are processed relative to the indexes of the state before the batch operation, and the indexes for the deletions are processed relative to the indexes of the state after all the insertions in the batch operation.

For me the first and second sentence are a bit contradictory. If the deletes are processed before the inserts, than the indexes of the inserts should be relative to the state after the deletes have been processed and not to the state before the batch operation.

I would perform the following actions in a `performBatchUpdates:completion:` block (for updating sections only).

1. Deletes

   - Given a sorted array of items.
   - Find the indexes of the items that should be deleted.
   - Delete the items in the sorted array.
   - Call `deleteSections:`.
2. Updates

   - Sort the items that have been updated.
   - For each item that should be updated:

     - Find the index of the item in the sorted array.
     - Find the new index based on the updated values.
     - Move the item to the new position.
     - Call `moveSection:toSection:` and `reloadSections:`.
3. Inserts

   - Sort the new items.
   - For each item that should be inserted:

     - Find the index at which the item should be inserted.
     - Insert the item at the position.
     - Call `insertSections:`.

Any hints or suggestions on this are very welcome.

Comment: Have you tried filing a radar to Apple?

Comment: Yes. And it looks like other having the same problem.